# Complex Trigonometric Limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \log_{\ \cos(3x)}\cos(2ix)$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

How to go about?

Use of L'Hospital rule and expansion is prohibited.

Comment: What Mathematica/Matlab says about it?

Comment: I haven't checked it there. @Stepan

Comment: $x\to 0$, but where does $x$ belong?

Comment: Use $\log_ba=\log b/\log a$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think the fraction should be reversed

Comment: What @clark said.  It's $\log_ba = \dfrac{\log a}{\log b}$.

Comment: I have made a few changes. Please try now. @YvesDaoust

Comment: @clark: yes of course. Typo.

Comment: This identity would be useful if LH Rule can be used. Please suggest some other method. Thank you

Comment: @AmanSharma If it is useful for using LH Rule it does not mean that it is not useful for other methods as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

As $\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$

we have $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(\cosh2x)}{\ln(\cos3x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+\sinh^22x)}{\ln(1-\sin^23x)}=-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+\sinh^22x)}{\sinh^22x}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{-\sin^23x}{\ln(1-\sin^23x)}$$
$$\cdot4\lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sinh2x}{2x}\right)^2\cdot\dfrac1{9\left(\dfrac{\sin3x}{3x}\right)^2}$$

Comment: @Deepak, Please refresh the page

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that.